# DAO Data bind Refresh() call - Run-time error 3061, 3075

Tags: sql, vb6, ms-access-2003

I use a DAO Data component to data bind control elements on a form. The query I create dynamically in a recordset which I bind to the Data component. This works pretty well. However, when I run **Data.Refresh** and the SQL Where statement contains references to the same table via different aliasses then an error shown.

*Note: the sql queries below run fine in the MS Access query designer*

```
Global gDB As DataBase

Set Data1.Recordset = GetData(select, from, where, order)
Data1.Refresh

Public Function GetData(select As String, from As String, where As String, order As String) As Recordset
  Dim sql As String
  sql = "SELECT " & select & " FROM " & from & " WHERE " & where & " ORDER BY " & order
  Set GetData = gDB.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset)
End Function
```

The following will work:

```
SELECT 
  WIZ_APPL.*,
  TRANS_PRI.Text AS LocalizedText
FROM 
  TRANSLATIONS AS TRANS_PRI,
  WIZ
WHERE 
  TRANS_PRI.Tag="prog" & WIZ_APPL.Id AND 
  TRANS_PRI.LanguageId=1 AND
  WIZ_APPL.Enabled <> 0
ORDER BY 
  WIZ_APPL.Id;
```

Until I try this:

```
SELECT
  WIZ_APPL.*,
  TRANS_PRI.Text AS LocalizedText, 
  TRANS_ALT.Text As AlternativeText
FROM 
  TRANSLATIONS AS TRANS_PRI,
  TRANSLATIONS AS TRANS_ALT, 
  WIZ_APPL
WHERE 
  TRANS_PRI.tag="prog" & WIZ_APPL.Id AND 
  TRANS_ALT.tag="prog" & WIZ_APPL.Id AND 
  TRANS_PRI.LanguageId=1 AND 
  TRANS_ALT.LanguageId=2 AND
  WIZ_APPL.Enabled <> 0
ORDER BY 
  WIZ_APPL.Id;
```

I get a Run-time error '3061':
    Too few parameters. Expected 1.

With a slightly different query, which includes an INNER JOIN on another table I get a Run-time error '3075':
    Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'TRANS_PRI.tag = "prog'.

```
SELECT
  WIZ_APPL.*,
  TRANS_PRI.Text AS LocalizedText, 
  TRANS_ALT.Text As AlternativeText
FROM 
  TRANSLATIONS AS TRANS_PRI,
  TRANSLATIONS AS TRANS_ALT, 
  WIZ_APPL
INNER JOIN
  WIZ_COUNTRY_APPL ON WIZ_APPL.Id = WIZ_COUNTRY_APPL.APPL
WHERE 
  TRANS_PRI.tag="prog" & WIZ_APPL.Id AND 
  TRANS_ALT.tag="prog" & WIZ_APPL.Id AND 
  TRANS_PRI.LanguageId=1 AND 
  TRANS_ALT.LanguageId=2 AND
  WIZ_COUNTRY_APPL.Country=1
ORDER BY 
  WIZ_APPL.Id;
```

The bizar thing is that the created recordset is fine and I can print the data. Also, the controls on the form are binding and showing data. However, as soon as I call Data1.Refresh I get the run-time error. Also, refresh() probably destroys the recordset (which is probably normal behaviour).

```
Set Data1.Recordset = GetData(select, from, where, order)
Do While Not Data1.Recordset.EOF
  Debug.Print Data1.Recordset!LocalizedText
  Debug.Print Data1.Recordset!AlternativeText
  Data1.Recordset.MoveNext
Loop
Data1.Refresh
```

---

UPDATE: If I assign the SQL query as String to Data1.RecordSource then the refresh works fine. However, when I assign the SQL query to a recordset then recordset.Name contains only a part of the SQL query. After a Refresh() call Data1.RecordSource is the same as Data1.RecordSet.Name. If the Data component tries to build a query from the shortened Recordset name then it obviously would not work.

Is this a known VB6 DAO Recordset issue?

Comment: What happens if you change your double quotes to single quotes? (around both instances of "prog")

Comment: It made no difference. I fear this is a DAO recordset bug. I will add it as an answer.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure about this but I think this is a DAO recordset and Data component bug.

It looks like the recordset uses the SQL query to create its name property however, it cuts the query short. The data component seems to use this cut query to refresh its internal recordset.

Bug 1: the recordset name property cuts the query short
Bug 2: the data component probably uses the recordset name property to retrieve the SQL query from the recordset or, it uses another property/function which also cuts the query short

Workaround or perhaps the correct method of usage; don't assign the SQL query to the internal recordset, rather use the Data component recordsource property